# php type hint for type of "function" or "closure"

Tags: php

What is the correct symbol to use if you want your type hint to denote a function?

I'm using php 7.0

```
function FuncA (interger $A, array $B, ??Function?? $C){
           $C();
}
```

Comment: Use Callable as type hint ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [`callable`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php):

```
function FuncA (integer $A, array $B, callable $C){
    $C();
}
```